# Cannot find custom control that is part of the project

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I have a custom control that is part of a larger project. The custom control is just a combination of two controls (GroupBox with a PictureBox inside). The custom control is added to a form. The custom control is the only thing on the form.

When I open the project I get the following error:

> Could not find type 'FLIR.ThermalImageDisplay'. Please make sure that
>   the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a
>   part of your development project, make sure that the project has been
>   successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any
>   CPU.

The custom control shows up under the project name in the toolbox. IF I drag the control into the form again I get:

> Failed to load toolbox item [custom control name]. It will be removed
>   from the toolbox.

I have searched and found the following four solutions:

- Clean and rebuild my solution. - Did not help.
- Right button clicking and adding the exe of my project to the Toolbox. I get a "The file is not valid" error. MY solution builds successfully.
- Close and reopen the project.
- Make sure that "Tools > Options > Windows Forms Designer > General > Automatically Populate Toolbox" is set to true. It is.
- I found one solution that said that Visual Studio did not support x64 from 2005. I assumed that this was no longer the case since this is a x64 project.

I have tried creating a new control from scratch. IT behaves the same way.

What could be wrong? Why is Visual Studio 2017 not seeing a custom control in the same project?

Comment: Set the Platform target of the UserControl to AnyCpu. Rebuild the Solution.

Comment: @Jimi - The custom control is a component of the project and the project is set for AnyCPU already.

Comment: From you description it's a UserControl, not a custom control. Give it it's own Project, targeting AnyCpu.